# SQL Query database

Tags: sql, postgresql

suppose i have a db table contianing name and marks out of 100 for some no of student. I want to assign a GRADE to each student depeneding on his marks obtained. I want result in the form as :

```
GRADE NAME MARKS
  A    X     85
  B    Y     75
```

let the criteria for awarding grades are as follows :

```
 A - if 85 <= marks < 100

 B - if 70 <= marks < 85
```

please somebody can give me a SQL query (preferably a postgresql query) to do the above computation.

Comment: it seems like you would only want to keep the numeric score in the db and move the business logic of determining A, B, C etc in your application business logic. you may want to include details about what languages / programs you are using.

Comment: @masterkrang I think this is a legitimate question.  It's possible to do this in postgres, so there is no need for an external application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could try doing:

```
select name, marks, 
CASE WHEN marks >= 85 THEN 'A'
ELSE 'B'
END AS grades
FROM your_table
```

Did you mean something like that

Comment: You beat me to it.  Have an upvote.  Also, it might do well to link to the relevant documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS

Comment: @NickRetallack: that's the wrong link. The `CASE` shown here is **not** a PL/pgSQL condition. The correct link is: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE

Comment: @Nick , well i executed the query given by sudhir on postgres , it just worked fine

Comment: The sample code in the answer is correct, but the first doc link isn't.  @a_horse_with_no_name gave the correct link, which is for use as an *expression* within a query rather than a *control-flow* statement in a scripting language.  The syntax is similar, except that the control-flow statement uses `END CASE;` instead of simply `END`, and control-flow affects execution of arbitrary statements versus returning values.